# xna drawprimitives: flip face normal

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm drawing triangles and they're invisible from the view they should be visible, so how can I flip the direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the vertex order in the vertex or index buffer. Or change the backface culling settings. E.g. set the `CullMode` of the `RasterizerState` to `CullMode.None`.

Additionally, make sure that there are no problems with lighting that make your triangles black / invisible.

Comment: Setting the ResterizerState to CullMode.None is not recommended, because it slows down the rendering process.